# How to deal with new coder arrogance?

Tags: communication

Dealing with one of those. You know the guys. 4-6 years of experience and gets some feedback from a user about a bug they swear doesn't exist. I've seen the bug personally happen, and yet, out of fear I think of being seen as bad, they refuse to admit it. How have you dealt with this and what can I do? In the past this person has reacted almost violently to suggestions like this, using company resources in an attempt to persecute. I can't get them fired, but I can teach them a lesson.

Comment: Do you have any sort of bug tracking process in place?

Comment: the lesson is simple: let them close the bug, let the user escalate it, and let management know that the colleague refused to properly investigate the user issue... nature will then take its course.

Comment: You should never try to 'get someone fired' or 'teach them a lesson' - Jesus, we're all just here to work and feed our families. Educate the guy on the right way to do things, and create some proper processes to follow to log and investigate bugs.

Comment: @JonStory Or he/she could simply take a screen shot or steps to repeat the bug. For example if the email said, "I don't see any bug" you could reply with, "Here are the steps to reproduce it and the screenshot."

Answer (score 8):

I've seen a number of this type of developer over the years.  They're always right, no matter what, and arrogant about their ability.

In truth, there is only one way to deflate them, and that is to *prove* that they're wrong.

> ...a user about a bug they swear doesn't exist. I've seen the bug personally happen...

If the bug is seen, then you need to reproduce it.  Prove that the issue exists and make sure the steps to do so are well documented in your bug tracking system.  This will firstly formalise the bug, and secondly make it apparent that the developer isn't quite as perfect as he may seem.

> his person has reacted almost violently to suggestions like this

Have you feared for your personal safety?  Have others?  If this person is acting in an unprofessional manner like this, then it needs to be flagged with your manager.  Keep records of when and where, under what circumstances. This is important as this evidence may be necessary at a later date if an incident occurs.

Really, the best advice I can give is to just track everything, both of bugs being denied and bad behaviour.  If he's arrogant for no good reason, then he'll come unstuck.  If he's got behavioural issues to go with it, then you absolutely *need* to document every time you are fearful and *why*.

Comment: Hi Jane, from experience reproducing a bug is often 90% of the work. So reproducing a bug for someone who apparently is too arrogant or lazy to do it himself is a huge waste of time for the poster.

Comment: @gnasher729 Oh, I agree that tracking down a tricky bug can take a lot of time, but if the OP _knows_ the bug is there, they would be remiss not to report it and how they got it.  A documented bug is harder for a lazy developer to ignore :)

Comment: @gnasher729: OTOH, if the bug has not yet had reproduction steps determined for it, then it should not yet be on your bug tracking system and there is not yet any reason to insist that the bug insists. So, in short, it's not "a waste of time"; it's your job.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i think the point is that it isn't the OPs job but rather that of the colleague who swears its not a bug. Nobody likes doing allt he grunt work (reproduction in dev env) so someone else can come along and dot he fun part (the coding) to fix it.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: No, it isn't that guy's job. When a bug is raised, proof of its existence must be provided. I agree it would be nice if this guy didn't jump to "I don't believe you" every time, but it's not his responsibility to disprove himself.

Comment: I think a good developer will at least try to reproduce it. The OP doesn't make it clear if the coder in question has tried and didn't get the bug to happen. One thing people who aren't coders don't realize is that we have a mental model in our heads of how people will do things, and that is how we navigate through the software when testing. It can be very hard to figure out what "unhappy path" a user actually took to get to a bug.

Comment: @gnasher729 I disagree with that. Part of being in a team is to help others fix the product you're working on. With a mentality of "it isn't my code that's broken" will only hurt you in the future because you might get that project soon and you'll have to revisit something you could have fixed long ago. If you describe the bug, got it documented, and everyone still disagrees then you can simply move on and forget it.

Comment: @Dan: Not when you are working with a colleague how habitually tries to deflect any difficult work away from himself. Amy: That's the difference between a good and a not so good developer. Lightness: "I did something in this area and it crashed, and I did something else in the same area and it crashed again". That from a serious tester should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

On one hand, there are bugs that are very hard to reproduce.

On the other hand, with 4-6 years he is a newbie, and I know from experience that whenever I was sure that a bug couldn't possibly exist, it did. There's the first rule of debugging code, which apparently he hasn't learned yet: "Whatever you know about this bug, it's wrong". That applies first of all to his statement "this bug cannot possibly exist".

In many cases, reproducing the bug is the hard bit. Once you know how to reproduce it, the fault in your code is often either obvious or very easy to find. So if he claims that a bug isn't possible, tell him from me that he just isn't a good developer.

And there's the second rule of debugging: "The problem is there because there is something wrong with the code". That's an absolute essential. People who don't understand this rule waste everyone's time including their own by claiming a bug is not possible, it is a hardware problem, it is a compiler problem, it's just gremlins that don't like you, instead of concentrating on finding and fixing the problem.

Comment: Nothing here I disagree with, +1 :)

Comment: _"if he claims that a bug isn't possible, tell him from me that he just isn't a good developer."_ Not wonderful advice.

Comment: _"The problem is there because there is something wrong with the code"_ If you'd ever actually worked with hardware, you'd know this is not always true. We've had five bugs closed as invalid last week because the problem was caused by badly soldered RAM.

Comment: @JaneS, of course there is something to disagree with. Many bugs happen through poor understanding of requirements or flat out poor requirements, not just because "there is something wrong with the code."

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit /true. Just wasted the entire last week finding the bug in the firmware of a magnetic stripe reader, just to find out, that our consumer has been botching around and made one pin loose.